# Make text widget fill out frame

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

[image]
**Why isn't the text widget filling out the entire yellow frame?**
*I even made sure to make the text widget sticky - what am I missing?`*

(`can_frame` is short for canvas_frame - the name I gave the frame that I putted into the canvas

```
from tkinter import *
enter code here
class window:
def __init__(self, root):
    root.grid_rowconfigure   (0, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    self.frame = Frame(root)
    self.frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
    self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame)
    self.can_frame = Frame(self.canvas, bg='yellow')
    self.canvas.grid(   row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    self.can_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    self.canvas.grid_columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1)
    self.canvas.grid_rowconfigure(   (0,1), weight=1)

    self._frame_id = self.canvas.create_window((1,1), window=self.can_frame, anchor='sw', tags="self.frame")
    self.canvas.bind(    '<Configure>', self.resize_frame)
    self.can_frame.bind( '<Configure>', self.onFrameConfigure)

    inp = Text(self.can_frame, width=40, relief='groove')   # TEXT WIDGET CREATED HERE
    inp.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew') # it's sticky so why isn't it filling out the -
                                             # - yellow frame?

def resize_frame(self, e):
    self.canvas.itemconfig(self._frame_id, height=e.height, width=e.width)

def onFrameConfigure(self, e):
    # update scrollregion after starting 'mainloop'
    # when all widgets are in canvas
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))
```

Please don't post any solution without a canvas, I need the canvas to create a scrollbar later on, in order to scroll through all of different text widgets.
**Thanks!**

Comment: The indentation of your code is broken.

Comment: Why are you putting a text widget in a frame in a canvas? That's very unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `grid`, you should always give at least one row and one column a positive weight. In your case, you have not given a weight to any of the columns in `can_frame`, so any extra space will go unused.

Comment: do you know what the first tuple indicates? 
self.canvas.create_window((20,20))

Comment: @Bjango: the x and y coordinate where the window should be placed.